# Может ли один блок catch заниматься обработкой и исключений типа NullPointerException, и IOException?

Tags: java

Вопрос из теста. (мой вариант жирным)
Может ли один блок catch заниматься обработкой и исключений типа NullPointerException, и IOException?

1. да
2. **Нет**

Comment: Открой Debug режим и позырь что происходит чувак ниже тебя на ответ подтолкнул

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Can I catch multiple Java exceptions in the same catch clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3495926/4279)

Comment: Ловить `NullPointerException` в блоке `catch`? Этого делать не стоит.

Answer (score 1):

Для решения таких вопросов у Вас должен быть тестовый класс и чуточку желания разобраться самому:

```
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class ExceptionTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                nullPointerException();
                iOException();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getClass().getName());
            }
        }

        private static void nullPointerException() {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        private static void iOException() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException();
        }
    }
```

Я Вас немного подтолкну...

Comment: Это ж не правильно ) Ваш блок занимается не только этими двумя исключениями, конечно в вопросе это явно не прописано, но я так понимаю что ожидалось такое: `catch (NullPointerException |  IOException ex)`. Но ответ и правда легко гуглится, проверил по запросу "several exceptions in one catch" - первая ссылка.

Comment: Не очень понятно что вы хотели  этим сказать(я не волшебник, я только учусь). спасибо за ответ. Но в тесте сказано в одном блоке catсh...Так как вы показали напрашивается ответ "да".Я так понимаю речь все-таки идет:            try {

            } catch (NullPointerException | IOException e) {
                
            }

Comment: Опередили чуток.Спасибо

Comment: @Uraty Неправильно для чего? )

Comment: @user293633 Если мне кто-то объяснит и покажет необходимость и полезность использования вот такого сахара: NullPointerException | IOException e я буду только за, в остальных случаях мой пример это наиболее употребимая практика, так как происходит отлов любых и непроверяемых в том числе ошибок.

Comment: @ezhov_da возникают ситуации, когда конкретные типы исключений нужно обработать не так, как остальные. Поэтому они попадают в свои `catch`-ы, а остальные - в последний (`catch (Exception e)`). Причем вполне возможна ситуация, в которой особой (и при этом одинаковой) обработки требует не один тип исключения, а несколько, где и пригодится multi-catch.

Comment: @Regent спасибо, за ответ, но для меня случай "когда конкретные типы исключений нужно обработать не так, как остальные" подразумевает сам по себе multi-catch, в контексте же вопроса multi-catch не нужен или как минимум не оговаривается о других типах исключений, по-этому я сделал вывод, что их всего 2 и логика обработки одна.

Comment: Друзья, спасибо за участие!Хочу напомнить что это учебный тест. Значит я ответил верно сразу?

Comment: @user293633 вот как раз про то, что это тест, не стоило упоминать в вопросе, а вместо этого приложить попытки выяснения ответа самостоятельно. Если вы, конечно, не с потолка ответ взяли. Один блок `catch` может заниматься обработкой исключений нескольких типов, так что правильный ответ: **да**

Comment: @ezhov_da фокус в том, что ваш комментарий выглядит так, будто вас интересует наличие пользы от multi-catch в общем случае, а не в разрезе вопроса. Поэтому и мой комментарий был таковым.

Comment: вообще да можно в одном блоке обрабатывать, но здесь IOException (это Checked) и NullPointerException (Unchecked), что собственно и смутило